# C#: very strange multithreading WebBrowser event behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

Here's some simple C# code:

```
    private void MainFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.ProgressChanged += WebBrowser_ProgressChanged;
        webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    private void WebBrowser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("WebBrowser progress changed, TID = {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    }
```

where MainFrm is a simple System.Windows.Forms, webBrowser is a WebBrowser control added in MainFrm (from the designer toolbox).

I would expect this code to either:

- show **multiple mboxes @ a time** with *different* TID reported (ProgressChanged event executed in separate threads)
- show **one mbox @ a time**, with the *same* TID reported (ProgressChanged event executed in a single thread)

What I see instead is **multiple mboxes @ a time w/ the same reported TID**!

This TID is incidentally also the TID of the thread MainFrm executes on!

Am I missing something here cause this behavior seems to me very counterintuitive: in my mind it shouldn't happen, cause **it would mean that a single thread executes in two places @ a time (?)**. How's this possible?

I've actually discovered this due to a bug in my app. That bug is a result of me relying on the fact that the event will be executed on **the same thread**, in other words that **it couldn't possibly be executed twice @ the same time**.

Thanks,

Corneliu.

Comment: There's no multi-threading here, it's all happening on the main UI thread. You're seeing multiple message boxes because `MessageBox.Show` starts a new - nested - message loop on the main thread. Then `WebBrowser_ProgressChanged` gets re-entered on the same thread (recursively, if you will). Check the Call Stack in the VS debugger and see that.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense